# changing the innerHTML() method?

Tags: html, television

Is there any way to change the underlying function of `innerHTML()` so a custom function will be responsible to add things to the DOM? Is there a way to change the prototype function of `innerHTML()`?

The reason I ask is because the Samsung TV's do not like when `innerHTML()` is used. Instead, Samsung suggests using their own API to write to the DOM. However, it would be nice if my app's codebase can be used across other non-Samsung platforms. So it would be ideal if I could change how `innerHTML()` works in one JS file so it uses the Samsung function, rather than creating conditional statements throughout the code. Plus, since I am using jquery, it would be nice if I can affect `innerHTML()` directly since jquery also uses `innerHTML()`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to look for the Samsung API and behave accordingly (use API vs use innerHTML)?

Comment: The question is based on a wrong assumption: `innerHTML` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this. It adds elements to the DOM in a more standard way, but allows you to still write HTML code to add to the DOM.

http://www.optimalworks.net/resources/betterinnerhtml/